# How to edit record in txt file? What problem?

Tags: java

I have a text file containing the following:

```
id,name,quantity,entry price,final price
1 Televion 15 2000 2400
2 Car 9 200 240
```

I want to edit name or quantity but [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5uGm.png) doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Don't add an image of your code, edit your post and add the actual code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You must try using CSV files instead of simple text files. Given that you have data that can be represented in a table with attributes and values, it is best to make it into a CSV file. You can use OpenCSV and make this process easy. Get the OpenCSV jar file and import it to your file. This will make your task easier.
You can get OpenCSV from here:
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

You can find references to use it here:
https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv